# Django formview returns object already exists error with a modelform

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a FormView that receives a string but it gives me a "objects already exists" error when I complete the field I give. What I'm trying to do is to create a view that checks if a certain "product" (model) exists, if that product really exists, redirect to another view based on the product "pk" to create another model.

Basically the course of action is like this:

- Check if product exists.
- if exists redirect to create order (model) view, else no nothing.
- Fill the create order form, if valid, create the order and assign the product fk relation to order.

Here's my code

**views.py**

```
class BuyOrderCheckProduct(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'buy_order/buy_order_check_product.html'
    form_class = forms.CheckProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(codename=form.cleaned_data['codename'])
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            product = None
        if product:
            # Never enters here because correct existing codename gives form_invalid, don't know why
            return super(BuyOrderCheckProduct, self).form_valid()
        else:
            # It only enters when I input a non-existent codename for product
            return super(BuyOrderCheckProduct, self).form_invalid()

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # I don't know why it enters here!
        return super(BuyOrderCheckProduct, self).form_invalid()  

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        # TODO: How to pass product pk as kwargs?
        return reverse_lazy('order_create', self.kwargs['pk'])

class BuyOrderCreate(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'buy_order/buy_order_create.html'
    form_class = forms.BuyOrderCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('buy_order_list')
    # TODO: Need to create a custom form_valid to add product fk to order.
```

**forms.py**

```
class CheckProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['codename']

class BuyOrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BuyOrder
```

**models.py**

```
"""
ORDER
"""
class Order(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'orden'
        verbose_name_plural = u'ordenes'
        abstract = True

    unit_price = models.IntegerField(u"precio unitario", )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(u"cantidad", default=1)
    discount = models.IntegerField(u"descuento")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code

class BuyOrder(Order):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'orden de compra'
        verbose_name_plural = u'ordenes de compra'

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="buy_orders", editable = False)
    bill = models.ForeignKey(BuyBill, related_name="orders", null=True, editable = False)

"""
PRODUCT
"""
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'producto'
        verbose_name_plural = u'productos'

    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=u'categoría', related_name='products')
    codename        = models.CharField(u"código", max_length=100, unique=True)
    name            = models.CharField(u"nombre", max_length=100)
    description     = models.TextField(u"descripción", max_length=140, blank=True)
    sale_price      = models.IntegerField(u"precio de venta", default=0)
    purchase_price  = models.IntegerField(u"precio de compra", default=0)
    profit          = models.IntegerField(u"lucro", default=0)
    profit_margin   = models.IntegerField(u"margen de lucro", default=0)
    tax             = models.IntegerField(u"tasa", default=0)
    quantity        = models.IntegerField(u"cantidad", default=0)
    picture         = models.ImageField(u"imagen", upload_to='product_pictures', blank=True)
    group           = models.ForeignKey(Group, verbose_name=u'grupo', related_name='products')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'll be appreciated if you give me a tip for creating a correct get_success_url() for this case.

Comment: Can you paste the errors?

Comment: You are using super() override within form_valid for form_invalid.  Why don't you just redirect based on if the object exists?

Comment: It returns me a "product with this codename already exists" error on forms.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found a solution for my error. What caused the `model already exists` error was my ModelForm CheckProductForm. Codename attribute is unique, so my validation always returned False. What I did was to change my orginal ModelForm to a Form. This solved my whole issue. And for the form_invalid in form_valid issue. I've overwritten my form's clean_codename function to raise ValidationError if product doesn´t exist.

Here's the solution I found:

**views.py**

```
class BuyOrderCheckProduct(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'buy_order/buy_order_check_product.html'
    form_class = forms.CheckProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = Product.objects.get(codename=form.cleaned_data['codename'])
        return redirect('buy_order_create', pk=product.pk)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CheckProductForm(forms.Form):
    codename = forms.CharField(label=u'código')

    def clean_codename(self):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(codename=self.cleaned_data['codename'])
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This codename doesn't exist.")
        return product
```

PD: Sorry for the dumb questions.